# DVI to HDMI - displaying bad

Tags: hdmi, vga

I currently have a computer with a ASUS EAH5770 (ATi Radeon HD 5770) 1GB GDDR5 video card, and 4GB ram, 2.6 GHZ i5 processor.
I just switched from a VGA (the blue one) to an HDMI cable. (Bigben Flat cable HDMI 1.3c) I use a Samsung SyncMaster 2032 MW, which has a HDMI input.

The weird thing is, that my screen is off-the-corner of the tv (so it's too wide) (1920x1080), and windows icons and text are not displaying well, though 1080p videos in YouTube are looking brilliant, just like pictures.

So i think it has something to do with Windows. I already have the ATI Catalyst Control Center with the drivers i received with my video card.

I do not currently know how to fix these problems. Do i have to reinstall Windows or so? Or is it (hopefully) easier?

Comment: DVI is normally white, VGA is normally blue.

Comment: "Off-the-corner" sounds like it might partly be an [overscan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan) issue. Your TV may have different modes to compensate for this, or the TV simply has a slightly lower resolution than 1920x1080. If it's the latter, you should still be able to reduce the computer's resolution output to match the TV exactly.

Comment: if i do it 1680x1050, which worked with my VGA (i said DVI :P) fullscreen, then it appears completely... but not fullscreen. There is black around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your TV may be configured with overscan, meaning it throws away a bit of the edges of the 1920x1080 image, and enlarges the rest to fill the screen.  This is done to avoid artifacts that sometimes show up in TV broadcasts.  The best approach would be to look for a way to disable overscan in your HDTV.  If that is not possible, you can probably [compensate for overscan](http://www.anandtech.com/show/1449) in your video card driver, but the image quality will not be quite as good because the computer's pixels don't map exactly to the TV's pixels.

Edit:  Wait, this is a [1680x1050 monitor](http://www.samsung.com/ae/consumer/computers-peripherals/monitors/lcd-tv-monitor/LS20PMASF/XSG/index.idx?pagetype=prd_detail&tab=specification), but you mention 1920x1080 in your question.  What resolution is your graphics card set at?

Comment: well after i changed the cables to hdmi it auto-set to 1920x1080. I can change to 1680x1050, and then it does display everything, but not full size, like it did with my DVI, which was fullscreen. The colors and stuff still appear weird.

Comment: It looks like the monitor is designed to "act like" a 1080p device over the HDMI input, even though it isn't.  Is there some particular reason you need to connect the computer using HDMI?  The manual says "You cannot connect a PC to the HDMI IN terminal." (page 22 of the PDF manual).

Comment: I just want good quality. Why is it not possible, that does not make any sense, why would there be a input then? for TV? why wouldn't it work then with PC?

Comment: If you want good quality, use DVI (not VGA).  Aside from the fact that DVI doesn't carry audio, it is in no way inferior in quality to HDMI.  The HDMI on this monitor is apparently designed to accommodate video sources running at HDTV resolutions (1080p) like Blu-ray players, DVD players, satellite boxes, etc.

Comment: then i'll hope i can get it back to the shop, which i think not. I have an adaptor with my videocard, but it is not HDMI -> DVI, but DVI->HDMI. That sucks. But I was already thinking of buying a new monitor, so i'll use VGA for now, and then later on maybe buy or a new monitor, or a new dvi cable.

Comment: Ah, so the issue is the lack of a DVI-DVI cable.  Here in the US you can get them from Monoprice.com for under $6, so hopefully you can find one inexpensively in your country.  Or maybe you have a friend with a closet full of excess computer equipment/cables?  Often monitors come with one, so maybe somebody has accumulated an extra.

Answer (score 0):

Check the hz setting, I had to use 59hz setting. (Which gets recognised as 60hz on the display.) Yes, ATI hardware. On my NVidia there is nothing like this, beats me what causes this.

(If I set my laptop display as primary, the 60hz is fine on the external. BUT. If I set it to primary (the external, that is), then I have to switch it to 59hz.)

Found so many relevant hits on Google..

Comment: on catalyst control center, it said it was 30hz, while my tv said 60hz. changed in control center to 59, but it changed it back to 60 :S

Comment: Hmm and thats it? It changes back for me too I just checked, but setting it to 59 and hit Apply fixes my problem. Kinda strange..but who cares as long as it works? :D

Comment: yh it doesn't. Read the comments to the other answer.